# Repeated requests to update icloud preferances

Tags: macos, imac

I keep getting requests to update my iCloud preferences.  I do so by reentering my password the the requests keep coming

Comment: Have you tried completely signing out and back in again?

Comment: Is it a legit password prompt or malware?  Please post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on my MacBook Pro (mid 2012) and I fixed it by following the guidelines mentioned here: http://www.rawinfopages.com/mac/content/keep-being-asked-your-icloud-password

> "Go to System Preferences, iCloud and clear all the ticks so that you
>   are no longer syncing anything to iCloud. You should also go into
>   every Apple app (FaceTime, Calendar, Messages, iTunes, Reminders,
>   Notes and any other app you can think of), check the preferences in
>   each app and if you are signed in to iCloud then sign out.
>
> After disabling all the iCloud sync options in System Preferences and
>   every single Apple app, return to iCloud in System Preferences and
>   tick all the boxes again to start syncing once more. You might also
>   need to sign in again with FaceTime and the other apps you signed out
>   of."